# Confidence intervals for non-negative least squares

Tags: regression, least-squares, bootstrap, constrained-regression

Can we use the non-parametric bootstrapping to compute the confidence intervals for the regression coefficients estimated from non-negative least squares?

I wonder whether this has the same issues noted for lasso because depending on the bootstrapping sample you get different coefficients can hit the zero boundary.